# Ошибка при запросе в Яндекс Директ

Tags: python, requests, яндекс-директ

Пытаюсь послать запрос и выдает ошибку:

```
Параметры запроса указаны неверно или достигнут лимит отчетов в очереди
RequestId: 7167824857849511136

JSON-код ответа сервера: 
{'error': {'request_id': '7167824857849511136', 'error_string': 'Незавершенная регистрация', 'error_detail': 'Необходимо заполнить для приложения заявку на доступ в интерфейсе Директа и дождаться её подтверждения', 'error_code': '58'}}
```

Вот код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from time import sleep
import json

# Метод для корректной обработки строк в кодировке UTF-8 как в Python 3, так и в Python 2
import sys

if sys.version_info < (3,):
    def u(x):
        try:
            return x.encode("utf8")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            return x
else:
    def u(x):
        if type(x) == type(b''):
            return x.decode('utf8')
        else:
            return x


# --- Входные данные ---
# Адрес сервиса Reports для отправки JSON-запросов (регистрозависимый)
ReportsURL = 'https://api.direct.yandex.com/json/v5/reports'

# OAuth-токен пользователя, от имени которого будут выполняться запросы
token = ''

# Логин клиента рекламного агентства
# Обязательный параметр, если запросы выполняются от имени рекламного агентства
clientLogin = ''

# --- Подготовка запроса ---
# Создание HTTP-заголовков запроса
headers = {
           # OAuth-токен. Использование слова Bearer обязательно
           "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
           # Логин клиента рекламного агентства
           "Client-Login": clientLogin,
           # Язык ответных сообщений
           "Accept-Language": "ru",
           # Режим формирования отчета
           "processingMode": "auto",
           "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "Host": "api-sandbox.direct.yandex.com"
           }

# Создание тела запроса
body = {
    "params": {
        "SelectionCriteria": {
            "DateFrom": "2023-05-01",
            "DateTo": "2023-05-16"
        },
        "FieldNames": [
            "Date",
            "CampaignName",
            "LocationOfPresenceName",
            "Impressions",
            "Clicks",
            "Cost"
        ],
        "ReportName": "Статистика",
        "ReportType": "CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT",
        "DateRangeType": "CUSTOM_DATE",
        "Format": "TSV",
        "IncludeVAT": "NO",
        "IncludeDiscount": "NO"
    }
}

# Кодирование тела запроса в JSON
body = json.dumps(body, indent=4)

# --- Запуск цикла для выполнения запросов ---
# Если получен HTTP-код 200, то выводится содержание отчета
# Если получен HTTP-код 201 или 202, выполняются повторные запросы
while True:
    try:
        req = requests.post(ReportsURL, body, headers=headers)
        req.encoding = 'utf-8'  # Принудительная обработка ответа в кодировке UTF-8
        if req.status_code == 400:
            print("Параметры запроса указаны неверно или достигнут лимит отчетов в очереди")
            print("RequestId: {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            print("JSON-код запроса: {}".format(u(body)))
            print("JSON-код ответа сервера: \n{}".format(u(req.json())))
            break
        elif req.status_code == 200:
            print("Отчет создан успешно")
            print("RequestId: {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            print("Содержание отчета: \n{}".format(u(req.text)))
            break
        elif req.status_code == 201:
            print("Отчет успешно поставлен в очередь в режиме офлайн")
            retryIn = int(req.headers.get("retryIn", 60))
            print("Повторная отправка запроса через {} секунд".format(retryIn))
            print("RequestId: {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            sleep(retryIn)
        elif req.status_code == 202:
            print("Отчет формируется в режиме офлайн")
            retryIn = int(req.headers.get("retryIn", 60))
            print("Повторная отправка запроса через {} секунд".format(retryIn))
            print("RequestId:  {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            sleep(retryIn)
        elif req.status_code == 500:
            print("При формировании отчета произошла ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте повторить запрос позднее")
            print("RequestId: {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            print("JSON-код ответа сервера: \n{}".format(u(req.json())))
            break
        elif req.status_code == 502:
            print("Время формирования отчета превысило серверное ограничение.")
            print("Пожалуйста, попробуйте изменить параметры запроса - уменьшить период и количество запрашиваемых данных.")
            print("JSON-код запроса: {}".format(body))
            print("RequestId: {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            print("JSON-код ответа сервера: \n{}".format(u(req.json())))
            break
        else:
            print("Произошла непредвиденная ошибка")
            print("RequestId:  {}".format(req.headers.get("RequestId", False)))
            print("JSON-код запроса: {}".format(body))
            print("JSON-код ответа сервера: \n{}".format(u(req.json())))
            break

    # Обработка ошибки, если не удалось соединиться с сервером API Директа
    except ConnectionError:
        # В данном случае мы рекомендуем повторить запрос позднее
        print("Произошла ошибка соединения с сервером API")
        # Принудительный выход из цикла
        break

    # Если возникла какая-либо другая ошибка
    except:
        # В данном случае мы рекомендуем проанализировать действия приложения
        print("Произошла непредвиденная ошибка")
        # Принудительный выход из цикла
        break
```

С токеном все в порядке. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Пробовал разные заголовки добавлять, но ситуация не меняется

Инфу брал от сюда https://yandex.ru/dev/direct/doc/examples-v5/python3_requests_stat1.html